# Adding parameters in stored procedure using c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to automatically add parameters based on the input of control numbers.

the following code will give me sp_INSERT @COL5, sp_INSERT @COL4, so on...

```
control = 5;

while(1<=control)
column = '@COL'
string setValues = "sp_INSERT'" + column + control + "';"

control = control - 1;
```

What I want to achieve is sp_INSERT @COL5, @COL4, @COL3, so on...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: no, if it even compiled, that code would loop forever assigning `column` the value `"@COL"`...

Comment: you tagged this C# but the code you post is not.

Comment: I just used 'sp_' prefix for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just... loop?

```
int control = 5;
string colPrefix = "@COL";
var sql = new StringBuilder("sp_INSERT ").Append(colPrefix).Append(control);
// note first item has different format due to comma
for(int i = control - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    sql.Append(", ").Append(colPrefix).Append(i);
}
sql.Append(';');
string s = sql.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop, not a complete solution, but it might help...

```
string myString = "INSERT ";
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    myString = string.Format("{0} @COL{1}, ", myString, i);
```